# Making a submit button an image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've looked at similar questions relating to this but I can't seem to find anyone having the same problem.

I'm attempting to us CSS in order to make a sumbit button an image. Here's the code

HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="search" alt="search" >
```

CSS

```
input.search    {
background-image:url(../search-icon2.png);
width:35px;
height:35px; 
}
```

This returns a broken image in the web page even though the image "search-icon2.png" is exactly 35px x 35px and is in the correct place on the server.

If anyone could suggest what might the problem be, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. J

Comment: if it returns a broken image then your path is wrong, check that the image is actually in that directory

Comment: where is 'search-icon2.png' located ?

Comment: `url(../search-icon2.png);` means 'search-icon2.png' file in folder which is one level up from where your CSS file exists.

Comment: Thanks guys, i've fixed the url but still the image does not appear, now just a plain text "submit" button appears in the size of 35px x 35px and i'm not sure why?

Comment: does your CSS is in HTML file or separated file?

Comment: it's separate, but I'm inserting the background image using dreamweaver browse so surly it should be the right path?

Comment: it doesn't work in IE8. which browser are you using?

Comment: Inspect your submit button in browser inspector and right click in css inspector for image and open the image in new tab to check image is getting loaded

Comment: Problem solved. I recently updated dreamweaver and it hadn't saved my settings which normally saved dependant files when uploading to the server. It stopped doing that and so the icon image was not uploaded. I should of realised! I'm just so used to the dependant files being uploaded automatically. Thank you all for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the image into the same location as the css file with the css having the url('search-icon2.png'). This would verify your path is truly correct and it's not another issue. If you still have an issue could maybe check the spelling of the image??

Comment: I've just tried this but I'm getting the same result, no image, just a plain text submit button.

Comment: What browser an version are you using?

Comment: Maybe try <input type="image" class="search" />

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a class="buttonImage">
  <span class="left_img"> Hello this is coding 
  </span>
  <span class="right_img"></span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttonImage {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.buttonImage .left_img {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/634e1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 7px 0 5px 8px;
    color: #1b1d60;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.right_img {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyeSO.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;
    height: 27px;
    width:7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttonImage:hover .left_img, .buttonImage:hover .right_img {
    background-position:0 -26px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ny28/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine just follow the following steps:
Search button image size must not be greater than whatever you initialize width and height in your css rule.
That means if you give width:100px and height:30px so images must be the same size.Just re-size your image with the help of Image editor software my personal preference is Adobe Photoshop.If your image size is greater than css rule so images may not come or image will be broken.I have edited your html as well as css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
       <head>
       <style>
            input.search{
                background-image:url(url.jpg);
                text-indent:-9999px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                border:2px solid rgb(0,102,153);
           }
       </style>
       </head>

       <body>
       <input type="submit" class="search" alt="search">
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Hope the answer!